# Access to Visual FoxPro 9 Base Software

Tags: msdn, visual-foxpro, dreamspark

I am a student with a Dreamspark Premium account that was provided to me by my educational institution. I am currently looking all over the internet for Visual FoxPro 9. My institutional Dreamspark web-store only provides the update to SP2 and not the base software. (totally useless without base software). I have contacted my institution but have not yet received a reply.

When I go to the official MSDN, and search for FoxPro 9, I find the base software that I need! The issue is, I can not log onto my Dreamspark premium account on that MSDN portal (this account does not exist is returned when trying to log on with credentials). To clarify, I can log onto the Dreamspark webstore with those same credentials. So how come when i check the FoxPro 9 subscriber restrictions, It says Dreamspark standard and Dreamspark premium qualify for the download, yet I don't have access to it? could someone elaborate or point me into the proper direction?

Does my institution just suck and possibly do not own the permission rights to the license for FoxPro?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question that should be directed to the software vendor's support system, as it is related to questions about the poster's specific account. As such, it has no lasting value to future readers of this site, as they will not have the same account.

Comment: But is it just my account? I could see people stumbling upon a similar issue when trying to access software that they have rights to but can't find the proper portals. I think this is a valid helpful question.

Comment: We don't know the details of your account or what it does (or does not) have access to; only the company that issued that account would have that information. Again, contact the software vendor's support staff,. We also can't advise you as to what permissions your university purchased; for that information, contact your university. Neither of those are located here at SO.

Comment: Okay Ken thank you. I will continue to await their reply. I am anxious to delve into FoxPro is all! :)

Comment: A better place to ask this would be http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/faqs.aspx (Bizspark support) or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home (MSDN Forums)

Comment: Thanks @Hank Yesterday!